# When We Delete an Element in a Javascript Array, How Are Other Elements Arranged?

Tags: javascript

I Have an Array:

```
{ value: "value", number: "1" }, { value: "value2", number: "2" }, { value: "value3", number: "3" }
```

Suppose I deleted the second data in this array. the third data now becomes the second data. but the value I set as "number" remains the same. How do I automatically change the "number" values in the remaining data after the second data is deleted?

Comment: if your `number` property only represents its order from the array, you don't need such value. Use `index` instead, `index` is provided as the 2nd args in every array function (forEach, map, filter...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-index all those values after deletion:

```
yourArray = yourArray.map((item, index) => {
  item.number = (index + 1).toString()
  return item
})
```

Comment: Which makes me wondering why we need a number property at all.

Comment: To be 100% exact, you'd need to make them strings again :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you remove it using splice and then you can reassign the number property by the indice of the array using *forEach*'s second optional argument.

```
arr.splice(1, 1);


arr = arr.map((x, ind) => {
  x.number = ''+(ind + 1);
  return x
});
```

```js
let arr = [{
  value: "value",
  number: "1"
}, {
  value: "value2",
  number: "2"
}, {
  value: "value3",
  number: "3"
}]

arr.splice(1, 1);


arr.forEach((x, ind) => {
  x.number = ''+(ind + 1);
  return x
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop after the removal to update the numbers:

```js
var arr = [
  { value: "value", number: "1" },
  { value: "value2", number: "2" },
  { value: "value3", number: "3" }
];
arr.splice(1, 1); // remove 1 item at index 1

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.number = (index + 1).toString();
});

console.log(arr)
```

PS: unlike some of the other answers, this does not create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work

```js
let a = [{ value: "value", number: "1" }, { value: "value2", number: "2" }, { value: "value3", number: "3" }];
function deleteIndex(index) {
    let len = a.length;
    for (let i = index; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i+1]
        a[i]['number'] = `${i+1}`;
    }
    a.length = len - 1;
}

deleteIndex(1);

console.log(a);
```